# How to delete multiple images added from UIScrollView on button click(Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

This is my button action where I am unable to delete image from scrollview

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed (sender:UIButton!) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // Cancel button
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Photo library button
    let libraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete event", style: .default) {
        _ in
        self.imageArray.remove(at: sender.tag)

        for i in 0..<self.imageArray.count
        {
            self.imageSelected = UIImageView()
            self.imageSelected.image = self.imageArray[i]
            self.imageSelected.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            let xPosition = self.imageSelectedScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            self.imageSelected.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.imageSelectedScrollView.frame.width, height: self.imageSelectedScrollView.frame.height)
            self.imageSelectedScrollView.contentSize.width = self.imageSelectedScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
                   self.imageSelected.tag = i
            self.imageSelected.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let button = UIButton()
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector (self.buttonPressed(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.imageSelected.addSubview(button)
            self.imageSelectedScrollView.addSubview(self.imageSelected)  
        }
       }
    }
    alert.addAction(libraryAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        imageArray.append(pickedImage)
        for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
            //ImageSelected is UIImage and I am adding multiple images in imageSelectedScrollView
            imageSelected = UIImageView()
            imageSelected.image = imageArray[i]
            imageSelected.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            let xPosition = self.imageSelectedScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageSelected.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.imageSelectedScrollView.frame.width, height: self.imageSelectedScrollView.frame.height)
            self.imageSelectedScrollView.contentSize.width = imageSelectedScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)

                imageSelected.tag = i
               imageSelected.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    //UIButton for user to delete particular iamges from the scroll view
                let button = UIButton()
                button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector (buttonPressed(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
                button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            imageSelected.addSubview(button)
            imageSelectedScrollView.addSubview(imageSelected)
        }
    }
    pageControlScroll.numberOfPages = imageArray.count
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Comment: why you are not using collection view....its easy to use and manage...

Comment: as i want to show page control below uiimageview.

Comment: I used collection view and problem got solved.